# Cannot remove account from mitro.co

Tags: user-accounts

I signed up for [mitro.co](https://www.mitro.co/) and imported my data. I am trying now to delete my account with data. I cannot find any way to delete my data from their servers. Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don’t have an account with Mitro, but here is what their privacy policy says (emphasis by me):

> #### ACCESS TO PERSONALLY IDENTIFIABLE INFORMATION
>
> If your personally identifiable information changes, or if you no longer desire the Service, you may correct, update or **delete it by making a change to your Lectorius account or by emailing our customer support at support@lectorius.com**.